# Cannot execute external PHP with Laravel artisan scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, octobercms

I have an external PHP script, that is processing an XML array to insert, update or delete rows in a database. This script lies in the root of the project in a folder called scripts and I can run and execute it via terminal with no problems whatsoever and it updates the database accordingly:

```
php index.php
```

I have also set up a schedule in Laravel (using October CMS syntax)

```
public function registerSchedule($schedule)
{
 $schedule->exec(public_path() . '/script/index.php')->everyMinute();
}
```

This however is doing nothing. I tried manually running the schedule with artisan in command line by:

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

And the output is

```
Running scheduled command: /Users/x/x/x/x/scripts/index.php > '/dev/null' 2>&1 &
```

Nothing happens in the database tho.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly states that it's a php script? That is: `exec('php ' . public_path() . '/script/index.php'`

Comment: I also think you need to add php before the path to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to generate a new key?

```
php artisan generate:key
```